# Delphi XE4 - TImage is not displayed at runtime

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

Note: In the original question I was in a hurry and wrongly assumed that the problem was related to VCL Styles, but at the end after some testing it seems to be related to the SynGdiPlus.pas, so I removed the original description.

---

**The problem**:

TImage correctly shows the image at designtime but not at runtime.

**The cause**:

`Gdip.RegisterPictures;//initialize SynGdiPlus.pas from Synopse.info`

**My solution**:

Removed the use of SynGdiPlus.pas and notified the author about the problem, use the built-in support for PNG files provided by VCL.

Comment: *having problems showing* is not a meaningful problem description. What *problems* are you experiencing? You say several times in your question that there is a *problem*, but you never once explain that *problem*. Images from an ImageList appear just fine for me in a VCL application using styles.

Comment: @KenWhite, in the subject I wrote "Images from TImageList doesn't appear". But now I will amend the question.

Comment: @EdwinYip, if you are using third party components, you must ask to the vendors if they support VCL Styles.

Comment: Found a clue - after removing `Gdip.RegisterPictures` of SynGdiPlus.pas from synopse.info for loading images other than just .bmp, the `TImage` is back to normal! Looks like it's not related to VCL Styles... But other controls using TImageList still have the problem, I'll dig further...

Comment: Please see Update 2 in the question text body for the causes I found, not sure whether I should delete the question, or post my own answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of SynGdiPlus is clearly deprecated.

The [current revision](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SynGdiPlus.pas) has a `NOTSYNPICTUREREGISTER` condition, which is enabled by default:

```
initialization
{$ifndef NOTSYNPICTUREREGISTER}
  Gdip.RegisterPictures; // will initialize the Gdip library if necessary
{$endif}
```

Ensure you got [the latest revision of the source code tree](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=Get+the+source).

Comment: Hi Arnaud, actually I intended to call `RegisterPictures()` , since wanted to use for loading image files. Now I use the RTL instead.

Comment: @EdwinYip Yes, there could be a single registration of image classes, at VCL level. You could use SynGdiPlus image classes, but you have to use them by hand, creating the class instances in code. AFAIK the SynGdiPlus classes were reported to be faster than the standard VCL versions, especially the regular TJpeg.